# Why is my find() not finding a specific HTML code even though it's there?

Tags: python, html, python-requests

I recently started to learn web scraping, and I ran across this problem:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
query = input("What city: ")
url = f'https://www.bing.com/search?pglt=169&q=weather+{query}'
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/114.0.1823.82'}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
s = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
weather = s.find('div', class_="wtr_currTemp b_focusTextLarge")
timescale = s.find('div', {'id': 'wtr_svg_cntr'})
print(timescale)
alert = s.find_all('div', class_='wtr_banner_content')
print(alert)
if alert == []:
    print("There are no weather alerts")
else:
    alert1 = s.find('span')
    print(alert1.text)
print(weather.text)
```

I have 2 problems. One with the timescale, and one with the alert
When I, for instance, type in 'sacramento', it shows me that there are no alerts. However, I checked the HTML code, and there is indeed a heat alert.

When I type in Columbus, it says the same thing, but there ARE no alerts in Columbus, so that works fine. But places that do have alerts don't work.

The timescale returns me the word 'Hourly forecast', but there is more text in the same string which has all the information, and it doesn't print that out for some reason (it should print aria-label="Hourly forecast (Fri 21) 6 AM: 65°; 9 AM: 75°; 12 PM: 91°; 3 PM: 100°; 6 PM: 102°; 9 PM: 85°; 12 AM: 78°; 3 AM: 71°, Precipitation: 1%". Does anyone know why?
Does anyone know why BeautifulSoup can't find it?
Thank you so much!
Weather URL: https://www.bing.com/search?pglt=169&q=weather+sacramento

Comment: Looking at these web pages and finding the elements by using `document.getElementById("wtr_svg_cntr")` , `document.getElementsByClassName("wtr_currTemp b_focusTextLarge")` , and `document.getElementsByClassName("wtr_banner_content")` returned the same results that your code is finding, perhaps these elements are not consistent enough to get weather data/weather warning data?